# How to install Rasa NLU using Anaconda prompt

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, rasa-nlu

I have anaconda installed, and I use Anaconda Prompt to install python packages. But I'm unable to install RASA-NLU using conda prompt. Please let me know the command for the same

I have used the below command:

```
 conda install rasa_nlu
```

Error:

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

- rasa_nlu
```

Comment: Hi! It would help your question to know if you've tried something already that didn't work, and what commands you may have already found by doing some research on the Internet. If you haven't done any research yet, I would suggest you start there. Thanks!

Comment: @darthbith I have used the basic command to install which is throwing error

Comment: What platform are you on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pip install rasa_nlu` from Anaconda Prompt as mentioned in the [documentation](https://rasa.com/docs/nlu/0.8.12/installation/)

Comment: Pip and Conda are used to manage packages. It worked for me. Can you tell me the error?

Comment: You cannot use pip in anaconda prompt

Comment: Pip should be installed in the Conda environment. Run `conda install pip` before installing rasa_nlu using pip.

Comment: @anaghas You *can* use pip in Anaconda, it is not recommended *if* the package is available from conda. But you didn't say what platform, so we can't check...

Comment: Can I use "PIP" in Anaconda prompt? Because i'm unable to, and with "Conda install Rasa NLU" command, it throws error. So how do I go about it?

Comment: It is throwing "Failed building wheel for Twisted" when i try installing Rasa_nlu using pip inside conda prompt

Comment: You can install the Twisted wheel file separately. Have a look at this issue  - https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa_core/issues/467

Answer (score 0):

if you are using anaconda prompt, close all your active py files and IDE and run the anaconda cmd as admin. Worked for me, if not install a c compiler

run : apt-get update && apt-get install build-essential
Then pip install rasa_core and nlu